# Can I use a ref variable spread through multiple Tasks?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I realize you can't use a ref variable in an async method, but I've set up the following function and will it run into threading issues?

```cs
public class HubResponse
{
    public ConcurrentStack<Foo> FooList {get;set;}
    public HubResponse()
    {
        FooList = new ConcurrentStack<Foo>();
    }

}
public class Bar
{

var hubResponse = new HubResponse();
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){    
    //Add task that sends http request async then reads and processes the body contents
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => {
        //do stuff, get var body
        ProcessJson(ref hubResponse, body);
        }));
    }
Task t = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}


public void ProcessJson(ref HubResponse response, string jsonstring)
{
   response.FooList.Push(new);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "threading issues"? And why are you using `ref` here? What is `HubResponse` and what is this code in the question supposed to do?

Comment: You almost certainly do not want to use `ref`. If you are using it, you probably misunderstand it, though, of course, you haven't shown your implementation so I guess I can't say with 100% certainty.

Comment: I understand how ref works. My ProcessJson function acts on the HubResponse reference by adding values extracted from the json string to some of its properties. My fear is that two tasks will try to simultaneously add values to a property which will throw an error if there is a locking issue, but I'm not quite sure if it will cause an error

Comment: You do not need to use `ref` at all, also you will encounter issues for sure because you are trying to access a shared resource (your `hubResponse` object) concurrently from multiple tasks. I can't see a good reason for that, you should really execute your async work and only when all tasks are completed add those results to `hubResponse`, not before.

Comment: If you need to push all of the responses to a collection for later processing, may I suggest another thread-safe approach? You can use a [ConcurrentBag(TResponse)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netcore-3.1), for instance. Add all responses there, wait for all the tasks to finish (like you are already doing), and then process each added response. Simple, clean, and thread safe solution.

Comment: It seems to me that you are overcomplicating things, something like `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` where `tasks` is a list of `Task<string>` (your response body) is more then enough. Then you may just use `tasks.Select(t => t.Result)` to obtain your json responses.

Comment: Why is your delegate marked async at all? You're not awaiting anything.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 each task in the list is an http request per the comment

Comment: @FedericoDipuma OK that makes sense, I just figured it would be faster to concurrently process the json responses because they can be fairly large in size (100+ kb) and sense I'm already running a set of threads, I could just tack it on

Comment: @Bugbeeb that's all fine and great, but there's no `await` inside your lambda, which means the `async` does nothing, which means if you actually needed `ref` for some reason there's not a problem

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I know what you mean, I do await the response it's part of the //do sutff section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the ref, the object is passed by reference. The concurrent collection is correctly used.

Comment: But am I able to access the concurrent collection safely on multiple threads since it is attached to the hubResponse object? Will the concurrently running methods be accessing the property separately by reference or  go through the class instance thereby causing issues?

Comment: The concurrent collection handles the concurrency for you. Check that you have try methods instead that return book so you can check if you insterted correctly